Effect of substitutions on bounds of Integration
I have a question regarding U-substitution for definite integrals. If I have a definite integral $\int_{b}^{a}f(g(x))g'(x)dx$, we can substitute the variable $u=g(x)$ to potentially simplify this integral. My question is, if this transformation brings the bounds to be equal to each other, i.e. $g(a)=g(b)$, does it mean that the original integral is $0$, or does it mean that the substitution is incorrect or inconsistent? When does it imply that the original integral is $0$, and when does it not?

Well, since $f(g)g'=(f\circ g)'$ by chain rule, we have $\int_a^bf(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int_a^b(f\circ g)'(x)dx=(f\circ g)(b)-(f\circ g)(a)=0$ using the fundamental theorem and $g(a)=g(b)$. So the substitution formula still holds in your case.

It does bring up a subtle point. Usually, change of variable formulas are only defined when $u=g(x)$ is invertible, which means $g’(x)\neq0$. The situation you describe can only occur when this happens, so one has to consider either side of this root separately. It still works out the way we expect in this case
